# Synchronization required for multithreaded GAE apps?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, concurrency

Google App Engine allows you to create threads if you use their `ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()` in conjunction with an `ExecutorService`. So, in order to allow the same frontend instance to handle multiple servlet requests at the same time, I am planning on writing code that looks like the following:

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpServlet {
    private RequestDispatcher dispatcher;

    // Getter and setter for 'dispatcher'.

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        MyResponse resp = dispatcher.dispatch(request);

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        // Use the 'resp' and 'writer' objects to produce the resultant HTML
        // to send back to the client. Omitted for brevity.
    }
}

public class RequestDispatcher {
    private ThreadFactory threadFactory =
        ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();

    private Executor executor;

    // Getters and setters for both properties.

    public MyResponse dispatch(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(executor == null)
            executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory);

        // MyTask implements Callable<MyResponse>.
        MyTask task = TaskFactory.newTask(request);

        MyResponse myResponse = executor.submit(task);
    }
}
```

So now *I believe* we have a setup where each frontend will have a servlet that can accept up to 10 (I believe that's the max for what GAE allows) requests at the same time, and process all of them concurrently without blocking. So first off, if I've mistaken the use of `ThreadManager` and am not using it correctly, or if my setup for this type of concurrent behavior is incorrect, **please begin by correcting me!**

Assuming I'm more or less on track, I have some concurrency-related concerns with how Google App Engine threads utilize the object tree underneath the `MyTask` object.

The `MyTask` callable is responsible for actually processing the HTTP request. In EJB land, this would be the "business logic" code that does stuff like: (1) placing messages on a queue, (2) hitting the Google Datastore for data, (3) saving stuff to a cache, etc. The point is, it spawns a big "object tree" (lots of subsequent child objects) when its `call()` method is executed by the `Executor`.

**Do I have to make each and every object that gets created from inside `MyTask#call` thread-safe? Why or why not?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all this to enable an instance to process multiple requests concurrently. GAE allows you to spawn threads if you need to perform multiple tasks in parallel when handling **a single given request**.

It could be useful, for example, if you need to contact several external URLs in parallel to get information needed to respond to a given request. This would be more efficient tha contacting all the URLs in sequence.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet (+1) - Duly noted. In that case, then, let's say that I *did* have a use case like the one you mentioned (hitting multiple URLs at once instead of in sequence). Would my code snippets above be correct? **More importantly**, would I have to make the entire object tree stemming from the `call()` method thread-safe? This is the root of my question. Thanks again!

Comment: No. You need to make an object thread-safe if it's accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Your task object is only accessed by one thread.

Comment: What if I injected each `MyTask` with the same global, singleton instance of a `Buzz` object (from inside `TaskFactory#newTask`)? Would I still be in the clear, or would I need to make `Buzz` thread-safe? Thanks again for all your help so far.

Comment: Yes, it would need to be thread-safe. Shared state must be thread-safe. I suggest you read a good book about multi-threading, because it's a very complex matter, and you can't learn it by asking questions on StackOverflow. I suggest *Java Concurrency in Practice*, by Brian Goetz.

Comment: I'm also reading Brian Goetz, the same book, and I can only approve. Read it. Also, take a look at the google docs regarding the web.xml, where you'll have to enable the multithreaded processing of requests by setting threadsafe=true.